# How to set edges using JSON in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js for one of my usecases. Here, I prefer to display the graph with only nodes in the beginning as shown below.

```
var cy1 = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: {
        nodes: countriesJSON
    },
    style: [ 
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'background-color': '#666',
            'label': 'data(id)'
        }
    },
    {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
            'width': 1,
            'line-color': '#aaa',
        }
    }
    ]
});

cy1.layout({
        name: 'circle'
});
```

Now, inside a function, I will form the edges as like this

```
function myfunc(){

  ...
  ...
  allRoutes.map(function(d){
            var inner={};
            var obj = {}
            inner["id"]="edge"+index                
            inner["source"]=data[0]
            inner["target"]=data[1]                
            obj["data"]=inner
            allLegsJSON[i]=obj;
            i++;
            })
  ...
  ...

  cy1.elements({ edges: allLegsJSON });
}
```

Once edges are created, I want to assign edges to the graph as above. However, this code is not working. Can someone tell me how to do this? I wish to assign the edges and then update the cy1 graph.

Comment: Note that's just an JavaScript object literal not actually JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This did this

```
cy1.add({ edges: allLegsJSON });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!